# What is the uncertainty of a discrete sum given the uncertainty of an individual element?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, standard-deviation

I have a measurement $$X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,$$ and I am interested to know standard deviation $\sigma_X^2$ of measurement $X$, assuming I know $\sigma_i^2$, the standard deviation of all measurements $X_i$. It is also known that $\sigma_i = \sigma_j$ for for all $i, j = 1, 2, \dotsc, n$.

Comment: I guess  $X_i's$ are independent variables?

Comment: Yes, each $X_i$ is independent.

Comment: Var$[X+Y] = $Var$[X]+$Var$[Y]$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29

Comment: "Each $X_i$ is independent" makes no sense. Independence is a property of a set of variables.

Comment: I think it is better to depict standard deviation with $\sigma$ instead of $\sigma^2$ which is more common to show variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_i$s are independent and you have already their standard deviations, say $\sigma_i$, for $X_i$, which seem to be the same, then the variance of each $X_i$, for $i=1,\cdots, n$ is $\sigma^2_i$, and so the variance of $X$ is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma^2_i=n\times \sigma^2_i$. As a result, the standard deviation of $X$ is $\sqrt{n\times \sigma^2_i}=\sigma_i\sqrt{n}.$

Comment: Standard deviation of independent sum = sum of standard deviations? Sure about that?

Comment: @Did Sorry, I had made mistake by "standard deviation" and "variance". I made some revisions, and hope it works now.